# How to set state properly in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 react components -

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import ContactCard from './components/ContactCard'
class App extends Component {
 
  render() { 
    return ( 
      <div className="App-header">
      <ContactCard name="hi 1" age={36} email="hu@yahoo.com"/>
      <ContactCard name="hi 2" age={67} email="hi@yahoo.com"/>
      <ContactCard name="hi 2" age={42} email="he@yahoo.com"/>
    </div>
     );
  }
}
 
export default App;

    import React, { Component } from "react";
class ContactCard extends Component {
  state = {
    showAge: false,
  };

  setAge = () => {
    this.setState({
      showAge: !this.state.showAge,
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contactCard">
        <div className="userDetails">
          <h2>Name: {this.props.name}</h2>
          <p>Email: {this.props.email}</p>
          <button onClick={this.state.setAge}>Show Age</button>
          {this.state.showAge && <p>Age: {this.props.age}</p>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactCard;
```

Toggle button is not working. i have set the state before render method. its not mandatory to set the state in the constructor.

Now the error is gone but still toggle button not working.

Whats going wrong?

Comment: You may consider deleting this question as it appears to have been more the case of a typo than a misunderstanding of React. It is unlikely to be useful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting state the wrong way. It should be:

```js
setAge = () => {
  this.setState({
    showAge: !this.state.showAge
  });
};
```

**Edit**

In order to make your app work as expected, you also have to set the click handler properly:

```js
<button onClick={this.setAge}>Show Age</button>
```

Comment: I did that and updated the code.. now the error is gone but toggle button is not working, showing no error in console as well.

Comment: Hey got my mistake i was doing <button onClick={this.state.setAge}>Show Age</button> instead of <button onClick={this.setAge}>Show Age</button>

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your code its this.setAge not this.state.setAge

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="contactCard">
        <div className="userDetails">
          <h2>Name: {this.props.name}</h2>
          <p>Email: {this.props.email}</p>
          <button onClick={this.setAge}>Show Age</button>
          {this.state.showAge && <p>Age: {this.props.age}</p>}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```